# What is the best way to evict unused records from string pool?

Tags: go, caching, string-interning, string-pool

I am implementing a cache in Golang. Let's say the cache could be implemented as sync.Map with integer key and value as a struct:

```
type value struct {
    fileName     string
    functionName string
}
```

Huge number of records have the same `fileName` and `functionName`. To save memory I want to use string pool. Go has immutable strings and my idea looks like:

```
var (
    cache      sync.Map
    stringPool sync.Map
)

type value struct {
    fileName     string
    functionName string
}

func addRecord(key int64, val value) {
    fileName, _ := stringPool.LoadOrStore(val.fileName, val.fileName)
    val.fileName = fileName.(string)
    functionName, _ := stringPool.LoadOrStore(val.functionName, val.functionName)
    val.functionName = functionName.(string)
    cache.Store(key, val)
}
```

My idea is to keep every unique string (`fileName` and `functionName`) in memory once. Will it work?

Cache implementation must be concurrent safe. The number of records in the cache is about 10^8. The number of records in the string pool is about 10^6.

I have some logic that removes records from the cache. There is no problem with main cache size.

Could you please suggest how to manage string pool size?

I am thinking about storing reference count for every record in the string pool. It will require additional synchronizations or probably global locks to maintain it. I would like to implementation as simple as possible. You can see in my code snippet I don't use additional mutexes.

Or may be I need to follow completely different approach to minimize memory usage for my cache?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do with `stringPool` is commonly known as [string interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). There are libraries like [github.com/josharian/intern](https://github.com/josharian/intern) that provide "good enough" solutions to that kind of problem, and that do not require you to manually maintain the `stringPool` map. Note that no solution (including yours, assuming you eventually remove some elements from `stringPool`) can reliably deduplicate 100% of strings without incurring impractical levels of CPU overhead.

As a side note, it's worth pointing out that `sync.Map` is [not really designed for update-heavy workloads](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Map). Depending on the `key`s used, you may actually experience significant contention when calling `cache.Store`. Furthermore, since `sync.Map` relies on `interface{}` for both keys and values, it normally incurs much more allocations that a plain `map`. Make sure to benchmark with realistic workloads to ensure that you picked the right approach.